# Why am I getting this error though BUILD SUCCESS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, routes, spring-annotations

I'm using spring-5.0.3

http://localhost:8080/firstapp_spring/greeting

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.actions.GreetingController@4275cbe5]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
```

There is no error during building project.

pom.xml =>

```
  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

class=>

```
package com.actions;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/firstapp_spring/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/firstapp_spring/greeting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        return "result";
    }

}
```

app-servlet.xml=>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> -->

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
      <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.ftl</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/hello" class="com.actions.HelloController"></bean>

    <bean name="/greeting" class="com.actions.GreetingController"></bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: pls check the url you are using is correct, I guess it should be "http://localhost:8080/myproject/firstapp_spring/greeting" .  Cheers

Comment: Add <mvc:annotation-driven /> which will configure your application context automatically for use with annotated controllers.

Comment: @SandeepKamath, Where would I add <mvc:annotation-driven /> ?

Comment: Please do add in your application applicationContext.xml file

Comment: I added in firstapp-servlet.xml, but got error when I do: http://localhost/firstapp_spring/greeting , Not found 404

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven /> if you are using this. You need to add <beans 
    
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        ">

Comment: I have this in firstapp-servlet.xml = https://bpaste.net/show/7bf572d4d913

Comment: @SandeepKamath, solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The request mapping that you've defined in your Controller class is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/firstapp_spring/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and the URL you're trying to access is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/greeting
```

You're missing the `"/firstapp_spring"` part.

Since you're using Spring > 4.3 you can take advantage of the new HTTP mapping annotations: [`@GetMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) and [`@PostMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html)

Your request mapping can become, the much shorter equivalent:

```
@GetMapping("/firstapp_spring/greeting")
```

Comment: I'm using spring-5.0.3 , I have replace myproject with firstapp_spring in original question.

Comment: have you enabled Spring Web MVC in your configuration?

Comment: I have this in firstapp-servlet.xml = https://bpaste.net/show/7bf572d4d913 , see pom.xml , there are spring-webmvc and spring-web there.